# change boolean value Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, database, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, boolean

I'm writing a simple code, where I need to change a boolean value instead delete whole row in my table in data base. I marked appropriate field with annotation:
" columnDefinition = " boolean default true ",

but when i saved a new instance in data base, it hasn't mark true/false on it. Then I put default value direct in field: " private Boolean exist = true; "

it start marking my instances, but when i try to change the value, it isn't work in both cases. (in first case I can't change null to false, in second case true to false)

I use PostgreSQL, I took my solution from official documentation [Default Column Values in JPA](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-default-column-values)

my entity class:

```
private long id;
private String colour;
private Boolean exist = true;

public Colour() {
}

@Id
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public long getId() {
    return id;
}

@Column(name = "colour", unique = true)
public String getColour() {
    return colour;
}

@Column(name = "exist", columnDefinition = "boolean default true")
public Boolean getExist() {
    return exist;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setColour(String colour) {
    this.colour = colour;
}

public void setExist(Boolean exist) {
    exist = exist;
}
```

my delete method:

```
 @Override
public void deleteColour(long id) {
    Colour colour = getOne(id);
    try {
        colour.setExist(false);
        colourRepository.save(colour);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println("delete is not possible: colour doesn't exist");
    }
}
```

table "colours" after running method deleteColour(): [in case of annotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9z4QK.png)

table "colours" after running method deleteColour(): [in case of field default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZgRl.png)

thank you for your time!

Comment: maybe I should use @Query in deleteColour() instead "colour.setExist(false)" ?

Comment: `columnDefinition = "boolean default true"` only affects DDL i.e. if Hibernate is creating your schema. it has zero effect on any runtime persistence operation.